# how to add the average hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the sample below, the average of the three times is 01: 42: 22: 566, my question is how to do this in javascript.

```
     <form action="/action_page.php">
      <label for="vOne">Value One:</label>
      <input type="text" id="vOne" name="vOne" value="01:01:01:100"><br><br>
      <label for="vTwo">Value Two:</label>
      <input type="text" id="vTwo" name="vTwo" value="01:30:45:700"><br><br>
      <label for="vThree">Value Three:</label>
      <input type="text" id="vThree" name="vThree" value="02:35:20:900"><br><br>
      <label for="sumValue">Sum Value:</label>
      <input type="text" id="sumValue" name="sumValue" value="05:07:07:700"><br><br>

      <label for="aResult">Average Result:</label>
      <input type="text" id="aResult" name="aResult" value="01:42:22:566"><br><br>

      <input type="button" value="average">
 </form>
```

Comment: Your question does not show much research effort. It might help to make an attempt and let us know where specifically you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to:

- convert strings to `Date` object
- calc average
- convert value to string

Try something like:

```js
const dates = [
  '01:01:01:100',
  '01:30:45:700',
  '02:35:20:900',
].map((date) => new Date(0, 0, 0, ...date.split(':')));
const average = new Date(dates.reduce((a, b) => +b + a, 0) / dates.length);
const averageString =
  average.toLocaleTimeString() + ':' + average.getMilliseconds(); 
console.log(averageString); // "01:42:22:567"
```

Comment: Thank you very much helped a lot Yukulélé!